# 'CTRL + X' not working on mac to save and exit nano

Tags: macos, terminal, nano

I am running the command below on my mac to add directories to PATH,

```
sudo nano /etc/paths
```

In the opened nano text window, after adding all the paths, `CTRL+X` doesn't work to save and exit nano.
tried `CTRL+SHIFT+X` which also doesn't work.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either :/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check the keyboard shortcut setting. It happended to me and it turns out was the keybind for Control was somehow binded to Command instead.